# jsf p:overlaypanel with dynamic content

Tags: jsf, primefaces, dialog, position, panel

I have a programmatically created list of hyperlinks (var="entry"), which show p:dialogs (with content dependent to the bean). due to some problems, i want to replace the dialogs with p:overlaypanels.

```
<p:commandLink oncomplete="dDlg.show();" update=":approvalContent" >
    <h:graphicImage value="resources/images/img.png" style="width:32px;height:32px;" styleClass="link"/>
    <f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{entry}" target="#{entries.actEntry}" />
</p:commandLink>
```

AND

```
<p:overlayPanel id="dDialog" widgetVar="dDlg" for=":nextTerms" hideEffect="fade">
    <h:outputText><strong>#{entries.actEntry.user}</strong> </h:outputText>
</p:overlayPanel>
```

i can't remove the "for" to make it independent and i also don't want to create a dialog for every list-item... or is this ok?

how an i update the content of the dDialog and make it visible when I klick on one of the graphic images with propertyactionlistener? as mentioined, it works with dialogs, but i need something what does not move around when someone zooms in the browser...

any suggestions?